# Creating a table for storing data in Haskell

Tags: list, haskell, data-structures, key-value

I'm trying to store data in a key-value style in Haskell. The idea is that I have an identification (Ident) and it can be a single value or a list of them.

I have tried the following structure:

```
type Ident = String
data SymTable a = ST [(Ident, Either a [a])]
                  deriving (Show)
```

The problem comes when I try to define the following basic functions to store/retrieve data from the data structure:

```
setVar :: SymTable a -> Ident -> Either a [a] -> SymTable a
getVar :: SymTable a -> Ident -> Either a [a]
```

I've tried several implementations but I can't get the compiler to work (accept types).

As a constraint, I can't use any external library (no Map or similars).

**UPDATE**

So my idea was to do something like this:

```
setVar :: SymTable a -> Ident -> Either a [a] -> SymTable a
setVar (ST xs) i a = ST ([(i, a)] ++ xs)

getVar :: SymTable a -> Ident -> Either a [a]
getVar t i = snd (head (filter (\x -> fst x == i) t))
```

**UPDATE 2**

Following @freestyle answer, i changed a little bit setVar so if you input an Ident that already exists, it overwrites it.

```
setVar :: SymTable a -> Ident -> Either a [a] -> SymTable a
setVar (ST xs) i a = ST ([(i, a)] ++ clearList xs i)
   where
       clearList [] _ = []
       clearList (x:xs) i
           | fst x == i = clearList xs i
           | otherwise = x : clearList xs i
```

getVar stays as he suggested:

```
getVar :: SymTable a -> Ident -> Maybe (Either a [a])
getVar (ST xs) i = lookup i xs
```

Comment: What code did you try, and what exact error(s) did you actually get?

Comment: `getVar` will be partial. After all, it might be that your `SymTable` doesn't contain the given `Ident`. You have to wrap `Either a [a]` in `Maybe` or similar.

Comment: List can contain single and many items. Do you really need to use `Either`?

Comment: @freestyle Yes, because for me 'a' is a variable and '[a]' is a stack.

Comment: @Zeta I tried to return Nothing if Ident is not present, but then should I change the header to Maybe Either a [a]?

Comment: We can help you if you help us to understand what exactly did you try to do?

Comment: @freestyle Updated with code

Comment: Still we don't know the error you are getting.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't see any problem with compilation of `setVar`, but more better is `setVar (ST xs) i a = ST ((i, a) : xs)`.

You have problem with `getVar`. The `filter` can "eat" a list, but you gave the `SymTable`.

So you can do like this:

```
getVar (ST xs) i = snd (head (filter (\x -> fst x == i) xs))
```

More better way:

```
getVar (ST xs) i = fromJust (lookup i xs)
```

But, if key doesn't exist you will get an exception. So, maybe you want like this:

```
getVar :: SymTable a -> Ident -> Maybe (Either a [a])
getVar (ST xs) i = lookup i xs
```

Comment: Thanks very much! I've updated the question with a litte modification on setVar

Comment: I think you can simplify `clearList` like this: `clearList (x:xs) i | fst x == i = xs` (don't continue)